# Cancan can not authorize create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

This is my controller

```
class IdeasController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def create
    @idea = Idea.create params[:idea]
  end
end
```

My ability file is

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.confirmed?  
      can :manage, Idea
    end
  end
end
```

But my spec return successful when create

```
context "when not logged in"do
  it "does not be allowed" do
    post :create, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:idea)
    response.should_not be_success
  end   
end
```

Need I must add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the controller ?

Comment: Probably best to start with a known example and then modify toward your code. I have used `cancan` much but this smells like a fundamental implementation issue

Comment: One more thing is :  there is `before {login_user user}` in other group

Answer (score 0):

Try: `cannot :create, Idea` in Ability model.

UPDATE:

`before_filter :authenticate_user!` is needed to set up a controller with user authentication.